# iBeacon: stabilize signals

Tags: ios, core-location, core-bluetooth, ibeacon

Currently I have 3 transmitters and 1 receiver (4 devices are iPhones) setup allowing me to work on Trilateration.

However, I found that the signals fluctuate a lot (even when 4 devices are put steady on tables). Is there any strategy to stabilize the signals?

Should I calculate the average X and Y to assume its position, or can I get assistance with GPS, or Wi-Fi signals?

Given that Wi-Fi is turned ON, bluetooth is turned ON, but not all devices have SIM card installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "accuracy" field distanxe estimate returned by iOS for a `CLBeacon` is already averaged over approximately 20 seconds, so further averaging is unlikely to help unless you are talking about very long periods.

You must be realistic about the precision you can get with beacon ranging in general and trilateration specifically.  Radio noise, reflections and attenuation from obstacles limit the technology to rough positioning.

See here for more info: http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/12/04/fundamentals-of-beacon-ranging.html